# WPF Resources Storyboard Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, binding, storyboard

I have the following animation which works like a charm:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Namespace:MathConverter Core:Key="MathConverter"/>
    <Storyboard Core:Key="MyKey" Completed="OnCompleted">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" By="135" Duration="00:00:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Duration="00:00:00.1" To="0">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now... my layout is dynamically built based on some specific base values. And I would like my animations to behave the same way. The problem is that if I modify my declaration as follows (the return value of MultiBinding Converter is absolutely correct, I double checked it) it just stops working properly:

```
<Storyboard Core:Key="MyKey" Completed="OnCompleted">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:0.2">
        <DoubleAnimation.By>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MathConverter}" ConverterParameter="((x - y) / 2) + z + w">
                <Binding Source="{Core:Static Namespace:MyClass.RealHeight}"/>
                <Binding Source="{Core:Static Namespace:MyClass.RealWidth}"/>
                <Binding Source="{Core:Static Namespace:MyClass.MarginInner}"/>
                <Binding Source="{Core:Static Namespace:MyClass.RealWidth}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DoubleAnimation.By>
    </DoubleAnimation>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Duration="00:00:00.1" To="0">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

"By" value, at runtime debug, is null. Why shouldn't a bind work here? Is there any workaround? Manually setting that value in code behind of course works... but well...

```
m_MyAnimation = (Storyboard)Resources["MyKey"];
((DoubleAnimation)m_MyAnimation.Children[0]).By = ((MyClass.RealHeight - MyClass.RealWidth) / 2D) + MyClass.MarginInner + MyClass.RealWidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way my Converter was handling everything return value:

```
public Object Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        String text = parameter.ToString();
        IExpression expression = null;

        if (!m_Expressions.TryGetValue(text, out expression))
            m_Expressions[text] = expression = m_Parser.Parse(text);

        Decimal result = expression.Eval(values);

        if (targetType == typeof(Decimal))
            return result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Double))
            return (Double)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Int32))
            return (Int32)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Int64))
            return (Int64)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(String))
            return result.ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

That kind of animation values are of nullable type... so I changed my method in the following way to make everything work like a charm:

```
public Object Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        String text = parameter.ToString();
        IExpression expression = null;

        if (!m_Expressions.TryGetValue(text, out expression))
            m_Expressions[text] = expression = m_Parser.Parse(text);

        Decimal result = expression.Eval(values);

        if (targetType.IsGenericType && (targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
            targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);

        if (targetType == typeof(Decimal))
            return result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Double))
            return (Double)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Int32))
            return (Int32)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(Int64))
            return (Int64)result;

        if (targetType == typeof(String))
            return result.ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```